Debugger on IntelliJ with Java on macOS
I’ve been dealing with an issue for over six months now. When I run the debug mode in IntelliJ with Java, it connects to the JVM, but it just keeps spinning without giving me control to perform step-by-step debugging or any other actions. I’m using macOS X, Apple M3 Max, Sonoma 14.1. This is not an issue with localhost or the connection to the JVM. Moreover, running the debug mode on the same machine works perfectly fine in Eclipse IDE. I suspect that the debug mode is not functioning properly on the Apple M3 Max chip.
Thank you very much in advance!
Nad
Here are some screenshot: screen1 -- screen2 -- screen3 -- screen4 -- screen5 -- screen6 -- screen7
